# How to check if the input contains any special char

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex, ext.net

I have a problem that a filed need to accept all the characters and digits (English, Arabic etc) except the special characters like

> ~!@#$%&*.()[]{}<>^+=:,;?/\'

more specifically only special characters will be treated as faulty.

I have wirite below code,

```
 var textToMatch='$a$';
 var pattern = /[^~!@#$%&*\[\]\{\}\<\>\^+=:,;?/\\]+$/
 var validationResult = pattern.test(textToMatch);
```

In this code it works well when I put "$$@" or "a$" in the **textToMatch** variable (**result: (false)invalid as expected**). **N.B: it only works when the last character is any special character**

but failed when I put any of the character (not special one) as last character in the **textToMatch** variable (**result: (true) valid which is not expected**) say for example: "$a".

I am really stucked here. any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Remove the `$` from the end in the pattern.

Comment: @devnull does not work. input i have checked: $a. if there is any existence of special character in the whole input it should be failed. that's what i need. by the way it now also failed for $a$

Comment: You'd additionally need to remove the negation within the character class.  `/[~!@#$%&*\[\]\{\}\<\>\^+=:,;?/\\]+/` should work for you.

Comment: @devnull :( not working. it is now treated the characters and digits as failed and excepts all the special characters. nothing is changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you only check *the end* of the string. You just need to add ^ at the beginning of your pattern, so the entire string needs to be composed of non-special characters

```
^[^~!@#$%&*\[\]\{\}\<\>\^+=:,;?/\\]+$
```

Comment: @HarveyA.Ramer Don't make me blush ;)